# yii 2 регистрация пользователя

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь расширить форму регистрации, добавить к стандартным полям новые, например телефон.

форма

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', [
        'inputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Название'],
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="form-group form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left">{input}<div class="form-control-feedback"> <i class="icon-link text-muted"></i></div></div>'
    ]) -> label(false);
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email', [
        'inputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'email'],
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="form-group form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left">{input}<div class="form-control-feedback"> <i class="icon-mention text-muted"></i></div></div>'
    ]) -> label(false);
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'telephone', [
        'inputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'телефон'],
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="form-group form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left">{input}<div class="form-control-feedback"> <i class="icon-iphone text-muted"></i></div></div>'
    ]) -> label(false);
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password', [
        'inputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'пароль'],
        'inputTemplate' => '<div class="form-group form-group-feedback form-group-feedback-left">{input}<div class="form-control-feedback"> <i class="icon-user-lock text-muted"></i></div></div>'
    ]) -> label(false)->passwordInput();
    ?>
```

после нажатия на кнопку данные попадают в контролер

```
$user = $model->signup()
```

с контролера в модель

```
public $username;
public $email;
public $password;
public  $telephone;

public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->telephone = $this->telephone;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();

    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
```

а тут получается `$user->telephone = $this->telephone;` NULL если в посмотреть то `print_r($_POST);` все есть, может что то не сделал или не не дописал

Answer (score 1):

Проверял его в rules? Так как по умолчанию все атрибуты не перечисленные в rules у модели являются unsafe, т.е. не безопасными и в случае не очевидного присваивания (через load или setAttributes) будут проигнорированы.